# xpath's text() does not return custom entities

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have the following XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ELEMENT root (entry*)>
  <!ELEMENT entry (#PCDATA)>
  <!ENTITY abc "a b c">
  <!ENTITY xyz "x y z">
]>
<root>
  <entry>&abc;</entry>
  <entry>&xyz;</entry>
  <entry>text</entry>
</root>
```

I use the following command to test my XPaths on it:

```
xmllint --xpath '...' test.xml
```

I am trying to match some custom entities with an XPath that looks like:

```
//entry[text() = '&abc;']
```

But it doesn't match anything. So I even tried:

```
//entry/text()
```

And the only result is `text` from the last entry, nothing from the first two. If `text()` doesn't return custom entities, is there anything else that does? Is there a way to match only entries containing `&abc;`?

Comment: I can reproduce this error. Applying the same XPath expression `/*/*` with `xmllint` and `xsltproc`, only the latter does transform the entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Conformant behavior

You cannot test against the `&abc;` internal general entity reference because an XML parser [must substitute](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#entproc) an internal general entity reference with its replacement text (`a b c`) when internal general entity references appear in an XML document's content.

You can see this in action by changing your XPath from

```
//entry[text() = '&abc;']
```

which selects nothing to

```
//entry[text() = 'a b c']
```

which selects the `entry` element containing the replacement text.

The replacement text should be available as text nodes, so

```
//entry/text()
```

selects three text nodes:

```
a b c
x y z
text
```

### xmllint's behavior

To get this expected behavior from `xmllint`, use the (oddly named) `--noent` flag.

Comment: The last part, the `--noent` flag, did the trick: `--noent : substitute entity references by their value`.

Comment: The `--noent` flag does the trick indeed! I actually use dom4j to parse the XML file, and comparing the `text()` to the replacement text of the entity works there too, without any weird flag. Thank you!